# Helm chart installation using plugin shows permission issue in binary

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have one helm plugin with binary `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root` permission in github.

When I install chart from the repo , I get below error

```
#  helm chkc install plugin-name xxx-charts/xxx-object-storage-plugin
Error: fork/exec /root/.local/share/helm/plugins/helm-xxx/xxx.sh: permission denied
```

changing permission using chmod command fixes the issue but thats not the way I would prefer to sort this out.

Similar issue I found

https://github.com/marcboudreau/vault-circleci-auth-plugin/issues/26

https://github.com/jetbrains-infra/vault-plugin-secrets-kubernetes/issues/5

Comment: what are looking forward to thn ? if changing permission way working but not want to use ?

Comment: I am looking for a reason behind this issue. I can always change the permission and go ahead with plugin installation but not everyone who uses my plugin would like that.

Comment: checked while uploading file permission is proper but at a time clone it's getting change ? maybe you have to commit file with executable permission